# Please explain the steps involved after $F(x+h)-F(x)-BAh=Bo_1(h)+o_2(\phi(h))$ in detail

Tags: limits, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, epsilon-delta, frechet-derivative

[image]

Please explain the steps involved after $F(x+h)-F(x)-BAh=Bo_1(h)+o_2\phi(h)$ in detail.

Note 1:here differentiable means Frechet differentiable

Source:Analysis for Applied Mathematics by WARD CHENEY(Page-121)

Comment: What about these steps don't you understand?

Comment: @FShrike:I'm not getting how ${\|Bo_1(h)\|}\le {\|B\|}.{\|o_1(h)\|}$
 implies that the last expression is $o(h)$? also how the epsilon-delta technique is leading to $F'(x)=BA$?